# Places for a "socially distant" walk

Tags: hiking, safety, united-states, walking

Where might I look for places on which to go for a medium length (3-5 miles) or longer walk -- and where I'd minimize my chances of encountering other people?

The Covid-19 pandemic is ongoing, and I've been trying to observe "social distancing" as strictly as possible. But it's become apparent that for my health I should really try to get outside more.

I live in a mid-sized American city (Columbia, SC) and have access to a car. Thus far I've just been going for short walks in my neighborhood. This has been okay, but there are a fair number people around and I feel somewhat uncomfortable being outside for longer than necessary.

There are a state forest and a national park nearby, both with hiking trails -- but the national park is closed and I'm informed the state forest is crowded. Are there other options I might not have considered? I'm happy to walk in wilderness, the city, or the countryside as long as I can easily avoid other people and cars. And I'm happy to do my own internet research on what's nearby, but I'm not exactly sure what to look for.

Comment: Comment only, since this is from Europe and I don't have firsthand experience from your part of North America, but: Does the state forest have trail sections that are further than, say, 5 km away from the nearest parking? If so => prepare yourself like for shopping downtown and endure the masses for the first hour. After that, the forest is probably yours. If it has "boring" trails, go there. I don't know the local customs about agricultural land and forests, but maybe it is possible to leave your car at a suitable place where it doesn't disturb passing machinery where the road turns gravel...

Comment: ... and start a "boring" hike from there (over here, e.g. forest paths are open to the public also in privately owned forests unless closed for specific reasons such as dangers like tree felling, or breeding places for endangered species, but these are very local closures, and many do not affect the larger paths/roads. Also the field paths are usually public land - and for trails on private land there is often a public right of way)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Thanks for your comment. Not quite 5 km, although there some relatively distant trails. The pandemic is especially bad in the US now, so I'm feeling reluctant to "endure the masses", although that would probably be a good option soon.

Comment: As far as local agricultural land and forests -- very interesting idea. My feeling is that this is unlikely to be possible here, but I'd be extremely happy if someone were to tell me that I'm wrong.

Comment: If you are flexible with time, consider e.g. a weekday morning hike at dawn. It may still be worth while finding out how crowded this crowded really is: I live in rural Germany, I can say that the field paths are unusually crowded right now. But where I am, this still boils down to having passed on my bike commute village -6km-> small town office during the last 3 weeks or so: several (≈ 5) other bikers (I'd put the normal number around 2), 2 or 3 riders some field away, a jogger, in short while I see maybe twice as many people as usual, that's still less than 1 encounter per day... But yes,

Comment: I'm definitely flexible with time. (Am a college professor and the semester is about to end.) Thanks for the suggestion! That's a good idea.

Comment: ... one local little wood that has a parking and is a favorite spot for walking dogs is more frequented. I encountered other people probably every 5 - 10 min during the first (and last) km from the parking, and two groups further than that - but that was Friday evening dog walking time. When I say rural, we still have a population density of 230/km², btw. (which is less than 1/10 of nearby Frankfurt...)

Comment: I think it depends highly on where you are.  Around here the only way you're going for a walk safely is to go to a nowhere.  The only places that are open that I haven't heard of being overloaded are class 3 or require crampons.  If you want to avoid the crowds you simply have to drive out into the desert and simply pick a spot and go off trail, or else go to the backside of the mountains (HCV required), there are almost no trails back there.

Comment: The "local custom" about agricultural land is that it's private property, and walking on it without permission from the owner is trespassing, which is illegal.

Comment: Helpful hint! Here in BC, a few  people walk **very early**  in the morning to avoid people on trails. I see police at my work site everyday and they know the least crowded spots. While “social distancing” and if the occasion presents itself ask your local Leos (police) when they are out and about. That’s what I did and got some good tips

Comment: Not telling you what to do, but just to keep things in perspective, our top medical officer, who's done a stellar job so far, stated that outdoor transmission is [extremely unlikely](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/please-go-outside-dr-bonnie-henry-says-covid-19-much-less-likely-to-spread-outdoors-1.5550191).  I suspect she was at least partially talking about Vancouver, not the rest of the province, and we can have semi-crowded trails.  I also suspect she was not talking about people sitting close together on the beaches/parks, that's probably still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Weekend Section of the Washington Post today has an entry about the Garden of the Franciscan Monastery of the Holy Land in America, which, despite living here since 1965 I had never heard of.

It has extensive gardens, woods and paths and you can bring your dog. It's free. Clearly this is out of geographical range for you, but Columbia must have **hidden gems** like this.

**Maybe you should buy a guide book to Columbia?** Of course, now that it has been in the WP, it probably will be crowded this weekend. But you have to look beyond federal, state and the popular local parks to find the hidden gems. Happy Hunting!

Take a look at [Only in Your State](https://www.onlyinyourstate.com/south-carolina/14-epic-hiking-spots-in-sc/) for 14 epic hiking trails in SC. I hope some of them are close enough to you to be practical.

Answer (score 1):

Hiking trails are not the place to go. I've seen large numbers of cars parked where they cross the road: In fact more than on a normal day. The paths are narrow and you won't be able to keep a Social Distance away from others - joggers also run up from behind, breathing down your neck, and overtake very closely.  The safest place is where you can avoid anyone you see walking towards you such as the beach or a large open park with vast expanses of grass.